# How to make a std::vector type-safe

Tags: c++, stl

I have an obect called an IndexSet, currently defined as a std::vector, that I want to define as a separate type.

I want to be able to interact with it just as though it were a vector, but I also want type protection so that I don't accidentally use a "normal" vector when I want to use an IndexSet.

I have been able to come up with three options for how to do this, none of which please me.  I am hoping that there is a fourth that I am missing.

Option #1:  typdef

```
typdef vector<int> IndexSet
```

This allows me to use an IndexSet exactly as I would a vector, but it gives me zero type protection.  I am able to pass a vector into a function expecting an IndexSet with zero complaints.

Option #2: Public Wrapper Class

```
class IndexSet
{
public:
  vector<int> indexes;
};
```

This will give me type protection, but it requires me to use a level of indirection interacting with it.  Instead of saying
    set.push_back(1);
I have to say 
    set.indexes.push_back(1);

Option #3: Private Wrapper Class

```
class IndexSet
{
public:
  push_back....
  operator[]...
  etc...
private:
  vector<int> indexes
};
```

This will give me both type protection and allow me to interact directly with the IndexSet as though it were a vector, but ONLY if I first create wrapper methods for every single method of std::vector that I want to use with my IndexSet.

Of course, what I'd really like to do is to just create a new class that inherits from vector but has zero implementation of its own, but I know that the standard library containers do not like to be inherited from.

Are there any other options that I'm missing?

Comment: You could make a class named `IndexSet` that inherits from `std::vector<int>`. Though I'm not sure what the policy on inheriting from standard containers is nowadays.

Comment: @It's about the same as it's always been: generally discouraged, but not technically problematic so long as you don't polymorphically delete the object.

Comment: @Cornstalks Could you elaborate?

Comment: Not an answer, because it is just a preference.  I would go for option 3, because in the end you probably only need a small subset of the API of an std::vector (you probably would have implemented the needed delegation functions by the time you asked this question (unless you really need a big API)

Comment: what would be the harm in accidentally using a `std::vector<int>` instead of a `IndexSet` ?

Comment: So you want something that is a vector, but you don't want someone else to accidentally use it as a vector?  What would be the purpose in that?

Comment: I think he might mean that he doesn't want any old `vector<int>` to be able to be passed as an argument where an `IndexSet` should be passed.

Comment: But why? If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it is a duck.

Comment: @MoreAxes: `std::vector` does not have a virtual destructor, so if you've dynamically allocated an `IndexSet` and `delete` it through a `std::vector<int>*`, the `IndexSet`'s destructor won't be called.

Comment: @DavidHammen: While duck typing can be useful, [some argue that strong/opaque typedefs](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3515.pdf) would prevent some accidental bugs.

Comment: @Cornstalks; You can dynamically allocate an instance of a class that does NOT have a virtual destructor if you use a `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @OP, see here: http://www.drdobbs.com/true-typedefs/184401633?pgno=3

Comment: For the duck comment -- I have several different "object types" that are not interchangable, but which are all stored as a vector<int>.  I want to prevent somebody from accidentally passing the wrong type in.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: I never said you can't dynamically allocate the object. I said you can't polymorphically delete the object; a problem which `std::shared_ptr` doesn't solve for you.

Comment: @Cornstalks; I heard what you said the first time and I raise you this: https://ideone.com/5YjnfM

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: Nice, I didn't realize `std::shared_ptr` created a smart destructor by default. [I did find a way to break it](https://ideone.com/VyuRZi), but here in this situation you are correct, it would not be problematic.

Comment: @PortMan "I have several different "object types" that are not interchangable, but which are all stored as a vector<int>."  This is an indication of an XY problem.  The real problem is how you are storing your data.

Answer (score 3):

Is there some functionality that differs between an `IndexSet` and a vector? Is there some difference in how these objects are used? If the answer is no, then why do you want to do this?

Your typedef does not suffice only if there is something intrinsically wrong with supplying a `std::vector<int>` to a functions that expects an `IndexSet`. That would suggest that an `IndexSet` does not satisfy an is-a relationship with respect to `std::vector<int>`. That in turn means that even if you could public inheritance, you shouldn't be doing so.

If the relationship is implemented-by rather than is-a, this suggests using either containment or private (and possibly protected) inheritance. This is much safer than public inheritance from a container class because programmers who use your class have to go out of their way to get a base class pointer. (The way to do it is to use a C-style cast. C-style casts can convert a derived type to a parent class even if the inheritance is not public.)

The advantage of using private inheritance in instead of containment *in this case* is that you can easily promote selected inherited member functions from private to protected via the `using` statement. You would have to write a bunch of wrapper functions if you used containment.

```
class IndexSet : private std::vector<int> {
public:
   // Bunch of constructors, elided.

   using std::vector<int>::push_back;
   using std::vector<int>::operator[];
   using std::vector<int>::cherry_picking_of_only_the_stuff_you_want;
};
```

**Update**

There are some non-member functions associated with `std::vector`, specifically comparison operators and `std::swap`. Making comparable versions for your `IndexSet` will require wrapper functions, but there aren't that many (six comparison operators plus `std::swap`), and you only need these if that functionality makes sense for this class.

Comment: An IndexSet is a vector<int>, but not all vector<int> are IndexSets.  All I am am trying to do is to keep any old vector<int> from being used as an IndexSet.

Comment: @PortMan - You were asked "why" in the comments on your question. So once again, "why"? What is it that makes you want to make this distinction?

Comment: Because they are being used for different purposes.  

A simpler example would be two different variables, one representing the temperature and one representing distance.

Both would be stored as doubles, and would not need any methods.  

What I am trying to do is to put them into other classes besides simple doubles so that it is not possible to pass a temperature into a function that's expecting a distance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's face it, one solution has all the advantages and just one disadvantage.

If you subclass std::vector, you just have to make sure you don't mix pointers to std::vector and your class, so nobody will delete a pointer to std::vector when it is actually of your subclass.

Whether this is feasible depends on your project. If this is an object that will be used by alot of people, in a public library, an OSS project etc, you might be safer wrapping it, else just subclass `std::vector`. You'll be fine.

Don't forget to add a comment at your class interface explaining the dangers. And you might be able do disable casting operators for extra safety (make your ctor explicit, ...).

Comment: What will happen if somebody deletes a pointer to a std::vector when it's actually of my subclass, if my subclass has zero implementation or new data members?

Comment: Good question, maybe the point is moot if your class is just empty, which would make it definitely the way to go. Personally I think it depends a little on implementation, but I'm not specialised enough to answer your question.

Comment: I asked it on SO, should see an answer soon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018430/empty-subclass-when-base-has-no-virtual-destructor-averse-effects-of-delete-ba

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for....`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp

`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(std::vector<int>, IndexSet)`

Comment: There's no `IndexSet::push_back`, no `IndexSet::operator[]` (amongst others) with this scheme. Even the author of `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` has moved on.