# Empty subclass when base has no virtual destructor - averse effects of delete base pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, heap-memory

Following up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016523/how-to-make-a-stdvector-type-safe) I wonder:

```
class MyVector : public std::vector<int> {};

std::vector<int>* obj = new MyVector;
delete obj;
```

Does this have any averse effects?

Comment: I would actually argue that publicly-inheriting `std::vector` is a violation of the is-a rule (Liskov Substitution Principle), and you're better off using private inheritance. Then you wouldn't even be using a `std::vector<>*`, you'd be using `MyVector*`, and all your problems go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the letter of the standard, you're invoking Undefined Behaviour, so anything can happen. But I'd guess that in most normal implementations, `MyVector`'s destructor is effectively a no-op (except for calling `std::vector`'s destructor, of course), so you'll be safe in practice.

Another question is why you're allocating a vector (-like class) dynamically in the first place. I'd say that's a rather unusual scenario. And if you actually need dynamic allocation, you could consider forcing ownership in a `std::shared_ptr` (or roll out your own smart pointer with a type-erased deleter), which is capable of fixing the correct destructor at the time of construction (thanks to @CantChooseUsernames for the suggestion).

Comment: Thanks, I don't usually create vectors on the heap, but it was more of a theoretical question to figure out if it could possibly be a bad idea to subclass like this (in itself unusual), but see the question referred in the question if you want to know why.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the class is empty.. it still allocates something (1 byte at least)..

https://ideone.com/CpNlNG

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


void* operator new(std::size_t count)
{
    std::cout<<"Allocated: "<<count<<" bytes\n";
    return malloc(count);
}

class MyVector : public std::vector<int> {};

class Empty {};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>* obj = new MyVector;
    delete obj;

    Empty* empty = new Empty;
    delete empty;

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
Allocated: 12 bytes
Allocated: 1 bytes
```

This is true even with O3 on. If you don't use the empty class though, it of course gets optimized out.

Comment: An *entirely empty* class has to be "artificially" upped to 1 byte. But the OP's class is not quite empty. You'll find that `sizeof(MyVector) == sizeof(std::vector<int>)`.

Comment: I was trying to figure that out, but on gcc the custom new operator doesn't seem to get called... Hadn't yet managed to test it. Seems more and more like there is no memory leak, right?

Comment: It does get called: http://i.imgur.com/Cle4E7Q.png For C++11: `The single-object version (1) is directly called by the standard library implementations of all other versions (2-4), so replacing that one function is sufficient to handle all allocations.` Anything below would have to override using the specific signature: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new